# Sub-Classed View with Form Not Returning Form Data

Tags: django, forms, django-forms, django-templates

I have a situation that I cannot reconcile. I have a sub-class that has a form that is not returning data from a POST request. The super-class also has a form and this IS returning data from the same POST request. That is to say that the super-class is requesting user input and there are several sub-classes that extend the super-class and request other data. The super-class always returns the data from it's part of the form, but the subclasses do not.

The subclasses return data in the POST, but the data doesn't make it back to the Django view. This seems like a bug, (but perhaps it's a feature) or another likely scenario is that I'm missing something. However, I cannot find it. Help!

A solution might be to have no super-class and just have a very non-DRY program. Yuck.

I've put in a few print() to terminal commands to look at what is coming back (or not coming back) to verify this.

I have also used my browser's Developer Tools to see that the POST does, in fact, have the necessary data in it that should be returned to the view for processing. However, this data does not make it back to the view.

The sub-class view code looks like this:

```
class MainView(SidebarBaseView):
  main_form_class = MainViewForm
  template_name = 'myapp/my_view.html'

  def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    context = super(MainView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
    context.update(self.get_context_data(*args, **kwargs))
    main_form_initial = {}
    for detail in context['my_data']: # my_data comes from get_context_data()
      field_name = detail.datatype.name
      main_form_initial[field_name] = detail.note

    main_form = self.main_form_class(initial=main_form_initial)
    context['main_form'] = main_form
    return render(request, self.template_name, context)

  def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    context = super(MainView, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
    context.update(self.get_context_data(*args, **kwargs))
    main_form = self.main_form_class(request.POST)

    print('\n','main_form',main_form,'\n') #to terminal

    if main_form.is_valid():
      main_form_data = main_form.cleaned_data

      print('\n', 'cleaned data', main_form_data, '\n') #to terminal

      for detail in context['my_data']:
        field_name = detail.datatype.name
        detail.note = main_form_data[field_name]
        detail.save()

    main_form_initial = {}
    for detail in context['my_data']:
      field_name = detail.datatype.name
      main_form_initial[field_name] = detail.note

    main_form = self.main_form_class(initial=main_form_initial)
    context['main_form'] = main_form

    return render(request, self.template_name, context)

  def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
    context = super(CompanyStatsView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    ...
    return context
```

My form make dynamic fields since I need to send it a variable number of fields eventually:

```
class MyMainViewForm(forms.Form):
  fields = {}
  field_names = ['one','two','three','many']
  def __init__(self, field_names, *args, **kwargs):
    super(MyMainViewForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    for name in field_names:
      self.fields[name] = forms.CharField(label=name, max_length=256, required=False, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'size':'36'}))
```

My template looks like this:

```
{% extends 'my_sidebar.html' %}
{% block content_right %}

<div class="container-fluid">
  <h2>Table</h2>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table">
        <tbody>
        {% for detail in my_data %}
          <tr height="50">
            <td>{{ detail.datatype.full_name }}:</td>
            <td class="text-right">{{ detail }}</td>
         </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table">
        <tbody>
        <form action="." method="post"> {% csrf_token %}
          {% for note in main_form %}
          <tr height="50">
            <td>{{ note }}</td>
          </tr>
          {% endfor %}
          <p><input type="submit" value="Save"></p>
        </form>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
  </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Any ideas?

The pertinent part of urls.py is:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

app_name = 'my_app'
urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^(?P<slug>[A-Z]+)/data/$', views.MainView.as_view(), name='main-view',),
...
]
```

Comment: Do you get any errors? In browser or terminal? You mentioned the `print`s you put there - which of them get printed?

Comment: Only the first print() is executed. I don't get errors. That is, the page is rendered after post but no changes are accepted to the notes. In fact, the note text does not appear to be sent along when the form is submitted. When I look a the data sent back from the super-class's form, I can clearly see that there are values being sent back and the cleaned data has the expected dictionary of values.

Comment: Only thing i see now is that in your example there's an indentation mix-up inside the if main_form.is_valid block. But that should raise an error

Comment: I don't see the indentation problem. Can you clarify? My problem occurs before that anyway.

Comment: My mistake - I thought there were fewer spaces. Did you try printing `main_form.errors` before `if main_form.is_valid()`? This could help you find the problem.

Comment: I just tried it and get no errors. Hmph. For some reason, the contents of the text boxes is just not being sent through to the view.

Comment: I also tried adding a field to the form in the standard way (not through __init__ ) and the result is the same: no contents of the template field is making it back to the view.

Comment: I am lost. Try opening the Network tab in your browser's Developer tools and see what data is being sent via `POST`. Just to be sure that there's really no data being sent and not a problem with receiving it. Also, could you share the `url` settings for this view?

Comment: Looking at the Params/Form Data I can see that the strings from the form inputs are present in the POST. I thought that the super-class post method may be responsible for stripping out this information, so I commented out the call to super in the post (and added in a context = {} to initialize it), but to no avail. The result is the same.